readthedocs build fails with little information
I have not used Readthedocs much since they updated their interface recently and separated Readthedocs Community and Readthedocs Business. I am on Readthedocs Community.
My local Sphinx build succeds with some warnings.
On Readthedocs, the build fails with no output.
The raw log is only a few lines:
Read the Docs build information
Build id: 26536333
Project: cajal
Version: ugw
Commit: None
Date: 2024-12-09T18:09:59.723398Z
State: finished
Success: False

There is a "Debug" page. The "Debug" page is also concise:
readthedocs-build --show-config
null

This would seem to indicate it can't find the config file at .readthedocs.yaml. It is indeed at the top level of my Git repository.
How can I debug this?
